# Disadvantages of ignoring Maven version number rules

Tags: java, maven, version, versioning

Are there any disadvantages when ignoring [Maven version number rules](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) besides Maven not being able to tell what the latest version is?

For example let's say I want to use a version number with 4 version parts like `1.2.0.1`.

Comment: If you just use a 4 number version like you mentioned...than it will work. The question is why you need 4 number versions...

Comment: @khmarbaise Because project management maybe wants it this way.

Comment: Does make this sense in your case? If it does not you should have a talk with your management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the maven version number rules is fundamental when you want to use any maven functionality that requires version "sorting", for example, [ranges](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html).

If you follow the format

```
<MajorVersion [> . <MinorVersion [> . <IncrementalVersion ] ] [> - <BuildNumber | Qualifier ]>
```

Then maven will sort MajorVersion as a number, MinorVersion as a number, IncrementalNumber as a number and BuildNumber or Qualifier as a String. Otherwise, the version will be sorted as a string.

Your example is not a good practice because maven will mistakenly consider 1.2.0.10 < 1.2.0.1.

Don't forget the special qualifier SNAPSHOT, used to build a version currently in development. Internally, maven expand the SNAPSHOT qualifer to a timestamp representing, not a release, but a "snapshot" of your app at a specific time.

For more information on maven version number, i recommend you to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855).